# PHP XML http response in an array

Tags: php, xml, arrays

I am a newbie in PHP. I am making a call to an http api using wget (the hosting site doesn't offer http_get). The call returns an xml set when do it manually. But it appears that my wget call is putting the response into an array.

I am unable to access the array and not sure where to go from here.

Below is my code. FYI -- The first 4 elements of the xml play_by_play object are: id, visitor, home, status.

```
<?php
exec('wget http://api.sportsdatallc.org/mlb-t3/pbp/99a0f209-2c69-49a4-99f9-8aebdf55b6e9.xml?api_key=API_KEY', $array);

//print_r(array_values($array));
echo $array["play_by_play"][0]->id;


?>
```

I appreciate any assistance with this!

Thanks

Comment: Just a tip, don't include your API key when posting a question.  You might want to log in to your account and request a new one.

Answer (score 0):

When you use [`exec()`](http://php.net/exec), the 2nd parameter (`$array`) will be filled with *each line* of the output.  That's not what you want.  That's why you can't access your values, it's just an aray of strings, not a parsed XML file.

I suggest you use [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/shell_exec) instead.

```
$xml = shell_exec('wget http://your.xml.file');
```

Then you can use an XML parser on `$xml`.

---

I don't know why you're using `exec` here when PHP has file downloading built-in.  [`http_get()`](http://php.net/http_get) is not a part of the PHP core, that's why your hosting doesn't offer it.  If they let you use `exec()`, then I'll assume they'll let you use the built-in [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents).

```
$xml = file_get_contents('http://your.xml.file');
```